# Instagram #access_token gets lost after redirect in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, instagram-api

I'm coding an app using Instagram's API.

As it is a pure JS app (angular js) the [implicit authentication method](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) is the one I'm using, however, after Instagram does the redirect to my `redirect_uri` the **access_token** in the url(which begins with a # sign) gets lost because the page does a reload.

Instead of getting an url like:

`localhost:9000/#/#access_token=[token]`

I get, after briefly seeing the token in the url, exactly this:

`localhost:9000/#/`

### Data

The url to get the access_token is something like this: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[my_client_id]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/&response_type=token`

In the .config of the app, in the routes definition, root is defined something like this:

```
.when('/',{
  templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'login'
})
```

Why could be this happening and how could I solve this issue so I can obtain the user's access_token?

Thanks a lot for any given help.

Comment: What you can do is that, When instagram hits your route,  you can store the token returned in $localStorage.